# Search in less with wrap-around at EOF

Tags: less

Is it possible to enable "wrap around" in less for the search? This means: If the last occurrence of a pattern has been found, pressing `n` will start the search again at the beginning of the file (so you do not have to press `g` and then `n`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes**, it's possible since release [v568](https://github.com/gwsw/less/releases/tag/v568).

Since [this patch](https://github.com/gwsw/less/commit/27e2643875e010c30f9d51eb1124855b707806f4) (full disclosure: I wrote it), the search modifier `^W` enables wrap-around search within the current file. Use it by pressing CTRL-W while on the search prompt. From the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html):

```
       /pattern
              (...)

              ^W     WRAP around the current file.  That  is,  if  the  search
                     reaches  the  end  of  the current file without finding a
                     match, the search continues from the first  line  of  the
                     current file up to the line where it started.
```

One way to make this the default behavior is via the *command section* in your config file (possibly located at `~/.lesskey`, see `man lesskey` for details):

```
#command
/ forw-search ^W
? back-search ^W
```

Comment: after 37 years we have wrap-around search…… still can't believe it!

Answer (score 6):

Probably not: the manual page for [`less`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/less.1.html) does not mention wrapping, and the description of the search feature does not hint it is possible.

Comment: So if I am in the middle of a file, there is no way to be sure that *pattern* doesn't occur anywhere other than typing `/pattern` and `n`  ***and*** `N` or `g` ***and*** `n`?

Comment: That's all the manpage gives you.

Comment: `ggn` is easily typed, basically, return to top, next...

Comment: It might be, but does nothing more than go to the top and search from the top, which was what OP wished to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can redefine the forward/backward search key mappings to jump to the begin/end of the file and then search.

Add these to the `$HOME/.lesskey` file:

```
#command
\eB back-search
\eF forw-search
/ noaction gg\eF
? noaction G\eB
```

Compile it with `lesskey`.

See `man lesskey` for default key mappings and actions.

Tested in version 530.